# laravel getting DB data for next DB request

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

```
public function show(\App\Models\Person $person){
    $casts = DB::table('casts')->where('person', '=', $person->id)->get();
    for($i=0;$i<count($casts);$i++){
        $movies = DB::table('movies')->where('id', '=', $casts[$i]->movie)->get();
    }
    return view('person.showPerson', compact('person', 'movies'));
}
```

When i want to foreach movies in view. It show's me just the last one. That's because of the for, but if i remove the `$casts[$i]`. Then it doesn't know which movieId (that's the $casts->movie) i mean. I want to foreach them all. How to send all $movies (in which the person from casts is) results to view. I think i need to use some relationships but i have no idea how to use them. Thx for help

```
This is the casts structure
         +"id": "4",
         +"movie": "2",
         +"person": "1",
         +"role": "actor",
         +"created_at": "2020-12-21 19:19:58",
         +"updated_at": "2020-12-21 19:19:58",
```

Comment: I think you have to read this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the `$movies` variable every iteration of the `for` loop so it will only have the last iteration's values.

If you don't want to use Models and relationships and want to query these tables separately I would just not use the `for` loop as you can ask the database for all the ones that match a set.

I would get all the movie fields from the `casts` and do a `whereIn` with that:

```
$casts = DB::table('casts')->where('person', $person->id)->pluck('movie');
$movies = DB::table('movies')->whereIn('id', $casts)->get();
```